# React JSX Dynamically changing the state of a component. Best practice and why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am pretty new at React and am following a video on youtube and working along + adding some more on top of it.

I have a button which when clicked, it decreases the `value` of object. In the video, the teacher copies the state to a new array, finds the index of the item, does the manipulation needed, and then sets the state again using `this.setState()`

This is the hardcoded state which I am using to practice. I want that when a button is clicked, the `value` to be reduced by 1 unless the value is smaller than or equal to `0`.

```
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, name: "Drink 1", value: 4 },
      { id: 2, name: "Drink 2", value: 0 },
      { id: 3, name: "Drink 3", value: 0 },
      { id: 4, name: "Drink 4", value: 0 },
    ],
  };

//and what I'm passing down to other components:

{this.state.counters.map((counter) => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            counter={counter}
            onDeletion={this.handleDeletion}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
            onDecrement={this.handleDecrement}
          ></Counter>
))}
```

Code from video:

```
handleDecrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const indexOfCounters = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[indexOfCounters] = { ...counter };
    counters[indexOfCounters].value <= 0
      ? (counters[indexOfCounters].value = 0)
      : counters[indexOfCounters].value--;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
```

Here is the code which I came up with that gives the button the same functionality:

```
handleDecrement = (counter) => {
    counter.value <= 0 ? (counter.value = 0) : counter.value--;
    this.setState(counter);
  };
```

Both ways provide the functionality needed, I am just hesitant to go my way in case this goes against best practice.

From reading the docs and similar state related questions, I can guess that the way provided in the video changes the complete state and my way only changes an object within it. Is the youtube code the correct way to approach this because the whole state is being set and we keep a single source of truth? Is my way bad practice?

Video is by Programming with Mosh btw: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0

Comment: In your second example you are overwriting the object previously stored in state with the updated integer value of `counter`.

Comment: leaving the practices aside, wouldn't your way of updating mean that you have a different structure for the state?

Comment: @RameshReddy yes that would be correct, I have updated my code to show also what I am passing in my ```Counter``` component. This is where I was getting the naming.

Comment: @pilchard correct. And the video snippet overwrites the whole state and not just one object. This is where I am having issues with understanding the best way to approach this.

Comment: Oh I see, you're passing a reference to the counter object. The problem with this is that you are mutating state by altering the referenced object directly. The code from the video, though verbose, avoids mutating state by cloning (via spread operator) at every level of the state object.

Comment: @pilchard I see, so I was almost right in my assumption, my way is more error prone because it splits up the information available in the state. If you write it out as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just confused on the reason behind updating the `counters` array instead of an object(`counter`) inside it.

It is because the `state` should always be updated in an immutable way. In your case, since the `value` is in an object that is in turn in an array, the `counters` array and the `counter` object should have a new reference after updating to properly inform React that the `state` has changed.

In your snippet `this.setState(counter);` will overwrite the state with the `counter`(so the other `counter`s are removed) and you're also mutating the object.

If you want to make the code a bit concise while also making sure that the state is updated immutably, here's an alternative:

```
handleDecrement = (counter) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({counters: prevState.counters.map(c => {
      return (c.id === counter.id && c.value > 0) ? {...c, value: c.value - 1} : c;
  })}));
};
```

In the above snippet `map` creates a new array and the `{}` object literal syntax creates a new `counter` object.